# PHP Session data clears after form submit

Tags: php

I'm storing session data in $relnum variable, as shown below:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['releasen'] =$_POST['release_no'];
    $relnum=  $_SESSION['releasen']; 
}
```

And displaying it in form text field, as shown below;

```
<input name="relnu" id="relnu" type="text" value="<?php if ($rel==''){ echo $relnum;} else echo $rel; ?>" readonly="true"/>
```

I am submitting above Form data in mysql, as shown below;

```
if (isset($_POST['submitM']))  {
    $faultd=$_POST['faultdistribution'];
    $faultdes=$_POST['faultdescription'];
    $faultsev=$_POST['faultseverity'];
    $faultt=$_POST['faulttype'];
    $faultn=$_POST['faultcmnt'];
    $rel=$_POST['relnu'];
    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `fault` (`fault-cmnt`,`fault-type`, `release_no`, `fault-discription`, `fault-severity`, `fault-distribution`) VALUES ('$faultn','$faultt', '$rel', '$faultd', '$faultsev', '$faultdes')")
        or die(mysql_error());
    echo "Data Added sucessfully";
}
```

The data is successfully submitted, but after that $relnum variable displays nothing. I am unable to comprehend what is the reason, as i am storing the data in session.

P.S: I am not using unset.

**Please help, what i am missing?**

Comment: Have you used session_start() at the top of your php file where you are using insert query?

Comment: Remove `isset` if the session is already started `session_start()` don't do anything and if `isset($_SESSION)`then the script will not store the value in the session variable

Comment: I've removed the isset($_session), but still same problem.

Comment: @OmerZia Is `session_start();` inside ALL your files?

Comment: Do you have `$relnum=  $_SESSION['releasen'];` on every page that uses that variable?

Comment: No, not on every page.

Comment: @OmerZia It must be on every page. Do that then try again.

Comment: @Fred-ii- at first the value display using this code:

`<input name="relnu" id="relnu" type="text" value="<?php if ($rel==''){ echo $relnum;} else echo $rel; ?>" readonly="true"/>`

but after submitting the form, value clears out!

Comment: have you resolved your issue? I am facing same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no need to post the session data in the form, else your code seems fine. You can do it easy way with posting it in form like below:

```
if (isset($_POST['submitM']))  {
    session_start();
    $faultd=$_POST['faultdistribution'];
    $faultdes=$_POST['faultdescription'];
    $faultsev=$_POST['faultseverity'];
    $faultt=$_POST['faulttype'];
    $faultn=$_POST['faultcmnt'];
    $rel=$_SESSION['releasen'];
    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `fault` (`fault-cmnt`,`fault-type`, `release_no`, `fault-discription`, `fault-severity`, `fault-distribution`) VALUES ('$faultn','$faultt', '$rel', '$faultd', '$faultsev', '$faultdes')")
        or die(mysql_error());
    echo "Data Added sucessfully";
}
```

it will work fine, please test it.

Thank you

Comment: Tried, but after submitting form the session variable clears out. (same problem)

Answer (score 1):

Remember `session_start()` only store the variable temporary on the server side, check have you `session_start()` on every page, for checking just echo your session variable on that page, if it did not echo anything then check the previous where from you are making session variable, it can help you sort out your problem by yourself.

Comment: At first the session variable successfully echo and displays data, but after successfully submitting data, it clears out and displays nothing on the same page.

Comment: Make sure you call session_start() before trying to use the session, and always exit() or die() after a redirect header.

Comment: i am calling session_start() before using the session.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code:

```
if (isset($_POST['release_no']) && !empty($_POST['release_no'])) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['releasen'] =$_POST['release_no'];
    $relnum=  $_SESSION['releasen']; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The session variable is `$_SESSION['releasen']`.  That is what is made available to you every time you have `session_start();` at the top of your code.  If you want to use $relnum, you'll have to set $relnum equal to `$_SESSION['releasen']` on every page load.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
session_unset();
session_destroy();
```

Hope this help

Comment: But i don't want to unset or destroy the session. Issue is why session value clears after submitting form?

Comment: Are you check your condition if (!isset($_SESSION)) you can reach in this condition?